variable global y comprobar variable image
Cordial saludo,
He declarado una variable publica
Public ctrlImage As Image

Lo que necesito es que cada vez que cambie el valor de una celda verifique cual fue el último Control Image asignado y ponga su propiedad Visible en False, lo que no se realizar es cuando inicio el macro obviamente la variable no tiene un valor asignado, ahi me genera el error.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
  If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
    Range("A5").Select
    Range("A5").Validation.Delete
    Range("A5").Value = ""
    If Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A2") = "FIGURAS PLANAS" Then
      Range("A5").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                       Formula1:="CUADRADO,RECTANGULO,TRIANGULO,ROMBO,TRAPECIO,CIRCULO"
    Else
      Range("A5").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                       Formula1:="ESFERA,CUBO,PARALELEPIPEDO,CILINDRO,CONO"
    End If
  End If
  If Target.Address = "$A$5" Then
    If Not IsNull(ctrlImage.Name) Then  'ERROR 91 ---> NO SE COMO RESOLVERLO
      ctrlImage.Visible = False
    End If
    If Range("A5").Value = "CUADRADO" Then
      Set ctrlImage = P1
      ctrlImage.Visible = True
      P1.Visible = True
    End If
    If Range("A5").Value = "RECTANGULO" Then
      Set ctrlImage = P2
      ctrlImage.Visible = True
    End If
  End If
End Sub


Creo que en vez de If Not IsNull(ctrlImage.Name) deberías probar con If ctrlImage Is nothing. Creo que te puede venir bien esta explicación

Muchas gracias voy a ensayarlo y te comento

El problema es como comento el usuario Esei, tu comprobación con la función isNull() es errónea debido a que esta función se usa para comprobar variables y no es apropiado que lo apliques a objetos del tipo Image, por lo cual debes usar If Not ctrlImage is Nothing Then. Sin embargo esto te producirá otro problema, puesto que las formas en Excel son del tipo Shape, por lo tanto, el código sería el siguiente:
Public ctrlImage As Shape

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
    Range("A5").Select
    Range("A5").Validation.Delete
    Range("A5").Value = ""
    If Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A2") = "FIGURAS PLANAS" Then
        Range("A5").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                   Formula1:="CUADRADO,RECTANGULO,TRIANGULO,ROMBO,TRAPECIO,CIRCULO"
    Else
        Range("A5").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                                   Formula1:="ESFERA,CUBO,PARALELEPIPEDO,CILINDRO,CONO"
    End If
End If

If Target.Address = "$A$5" Then
    If Not ctrlImage Is Nothing Then
        ctrlImage.Visible = False
    End If
    If Range("A5").Value = "CUADRADO" Then
        Set ctrlImage = Hoja1.Shapes("P1")
        ctrlImage.Visible = True
    End If
    If Range("A5").Value = "RECTANGULO" Then
        Set ctrlImage = Hoja1.Shapes("P2")
        ctrlImage.Visible = True
    End If
End If
End Sub

A modo de conclusión, primero revisar la función usada para comprobar si un objeto es Nothing (No Null) y segundo que el objeto sea del mismo tipo que se le quiere inicializar.
